# geochart: Adding html annotation to it or other any other alternative charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to Add a text overlay on the geochart. I could add the text only in the tooltip but its visible only when mouse hover/selection. But I wanted it to be always visible.

Below is the fiddle link. When I try to add annotation geochart is giving an error.

http://jsfiddle.net/aSrVH/
  Car data = new google. visualization. DataTable ();

```
Data. addColumn ('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip'
});
```

I couldn't change above to:

```
   data.addColumn({
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'
    });
```

Please let me know if this is possible in geochart or suggest me any alternative.

follow up question:
1. If text is possible can I add animation to it?( like fadein/out)

Comment: Sorry there is no way to do that currently, at least not directly. Good idea though. Perhaps you can figure out the positions of regions somehow (maybe wait for a hover event) and display your own HTML overlaid on top of the chart.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to geochart?

Comment: You could always go with D3, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo . You'll have to do more manually (hover event, your own tooltip), and you will loose old browser support.

Comment: But D3 is svg right? not canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fixed text with the option **displayMode: 'text'** and when hovered shows your customized box.

See example from developers.google.com/chart/ by clicking [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Text).

Comment: I agree. I would take the location of the texts like this and play the elements with Tippyjs